# UITableViewCell set gradient

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am overriding the UITableViewCell class:

```
@implementation UserTableViewCell

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:207/255.0 blue:207/255.0 alpha:51/255.0] CGColor], nil];

    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

...
// other methods specific to this type of cell
...

```
@end
```

This works great.  However when the device is rotated the cells gradient does not change properly.  I see a lot of examples where the gradient is drawn in the UITableView class, but I have already overridden the UITableViewCell class and am trying to keep the gradient code contained within the cell class.

There is no viewDidLoad for a tableViewCell and I cannot add the gradient to my storyboard (stupid), so I am not sure what to do here.

Comment: check the constraint in the interface builder-> click on the second tab from the right, make sure the image is stretch correctly. under autoresizing, set the inner box to control the stretch. Also set the customView you just created to have ClipToBounds = YES and Clip Subviews = YES

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  I have all that set.  Cell looks great on initial view, however gradient is drawn in code.  When you rotate the device the gradient is not drawn again with the new bounds of the cell.  awakeFromNib is only called once, never again on rotate.  This is my problem I am not sure how to redraw the gradient on rotate.

Comment: Try to override `layoutSubviews` method in `UserTableViewCell`. You need to update gradient frame within layoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 0):

@Keenle is correct:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:207/255.0 green:207/255.0 blue:207/255.0 alpha:51/255.0] CGColor], nil];

    [self setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
    [self.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

works just great.